# Redirect Plone 2 root to a new domain

Tags: python, redirect, plone

My old Plone 2 site is hosted on a free plone provider (say myoldsite.hostingxyz.com).
I have a new site on a new domain (say www.mysitexyz.com) and want to redirect the old site to the new domain (a real HTTP 301 redirect).

This is what I have for now :

- I created in the ZMI a python script called `Index`, containing :

```python
 container.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect('http://www.mysitexyz.com',301)
```

- Now if I use the URL `myoldsite.hostingxyz.com/Index` I have a good redirect to my new domain.

Is there a way to say Zope/Plone that my Index script is the default page of my site ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name it `index_html` and put it at the root of your site. Make sure you don't have a default page set.